# how to hide webpart from a group?

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

can i hide (not by code) a webpart ONLY from a specific group?

Comment: Are you able to use SharePoint designer?

Comment: yes i can, is there a way doing it in sharepoint designer?

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate a bit? what kind of group do you mean? SharePoint security groups? If so, you could try audience targeting.

Be aware though, audience targeting is not the same as real security groups, meaning someone who for  instance knows the exact location of a page hidden to him through audiencing, he can just enter the url and he'll see the page.

Comment: + audience targeting is only available in MOSS.

Comment: i want to hide the webpart from a specific AD group (and the rest will still see the webpart), can i do that using audience targeting?

Comment: YEs, you can create a new audience and add the ad group to it.

Comment: colin, this will SHOW the webpart to the specific group but i want to HIDE the webpart from a specific group

Comment: It will SHOW it to one audience so if users are not in that audience they won't see the webpart

Answer (score 0):

You have to use conditional formatting .
You can create conditions for groups